# Seeking file for Pakistan

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, pakistan

Can anyone tell me where I can find a file like this on Pakistan?

I found it on ochaonline.un.org I cannot find it when I search on there.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/38714310/Afghanistan-Settlements-Index-A3

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of data you are interested in, but have you looked at the OSM data for Pakistan?

You can download the shapefiles here: https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/pakistan.html

Answer (score 0):

There are lists of "Federally Administered Tribal Areas" at:

http://www.fallingrain.com/world/PK/

They are unhelpfully listed on different pages alphabetically.